# Facing scrapy selenium issues while using SeleniumRequest

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a very tiny script to parse the name of different restaurants from a webpage using scrapy in combination with selenium making use of ***[scrapy-selenium](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/#description)*** library.

My `settings.py` file contains:

```
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which("chromedriver")
```

My spider contains: (used middleware reference within crawlerprocess)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class YPageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Pizza+Hut&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=self.link,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        for elem in response.css(".v-card .info a.business-name::attr(href)").getall():
            yield {"links":elem}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'] = {'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware':800}
    c = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    c.crawl(YPageSpider)
    c.start()
```

However, when I run my script and go through the `downloader middlewares` list, I can see that `scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware` reference is not being activated.

***How can I make it a go successfully?***

Traceback I'm getting:

```
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: proxyspider)
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.5, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'proxyspider', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'proxyspider.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['proxyspider.spiders']}
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: f7cd144cc88f20f6
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-05-22 18:03:57 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 140, in create_instance
    return objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy_selenium\middlewares.py", line 71, in from_crawler
    browser_executable_path=browser_executable_path
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy_selenium\middlewares.py", line 43, in __init__
    for argument in driver_arguments:
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

[Full traceback available here](https://pastebin.com/G5PwJnhm)

Comment: Honest question: Why are you using selenium if plain scrapy seems to able to get what you need?

Comment: The url used within my script is just a placeholder.

Comment: Try copying your settings to the `custom_settings` attribute of your spider, see if they work then. Also, check the logs, at the beginning it should indicate which settings are overriden, so your settings should be listed. If they are listed, and you still get the same error, maybe the values of the settings are the issue, and the error is simply misleading.

Comment: Is it possible that `which("chromedriver")` is returning `None`? Have you checked how the settings look like in the log line about overridden settings?

Comment: It says `2019-05-22 15:54:15 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}`, so your settings are not being picked up. Have you tried using `custom_settings` directly on the spider?

Comment: Ain't it direct the way I'm doing above?

Comment: Now you might wanna check out the edit to offer any solution @Gallaecio.

Comment: Oh, I’ve just realized, thanks to your new log, that the log line about overriden settings would not mention `SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME` and such, as they are not built-in Scrapy settings :|

Comment: You could clone the scrapy-selenium code locally, install the local clone into your virtual environment (pip install -e <clone path>), and modify the local code to debug the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `File
>   "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy_selenium\middlewares.py"
>   line 43, in __init__
>       for argument in driver_arguments: builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not >iterable`

According to github source of that [line 43](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/develop/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py#L43) your application tried to read data from `'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS'` setting which is required for selenium middleware and is not presented in your code .

Comment: Thanks @Georgiy for the pointer. I never could have found it out. I would be very happy if you could guide me in comments how can I clone the scrapy-selenium code locally. This clone thing is totally foreign to me. Thanks.

Comment: As [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/tree/0.0.7/scrapy_selenium) project has relatively low number of files You can simply copy/paste source code of 2 it's files `http.py` and `middlewares.py` to your project.